# the universal covering space of compact Riemann surface(how the covering map be holormporphic?)

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I occured in this question when I was learning the proof of the Riemann-Roch theorem for effective divisors with the vedio [here](https://youtu.be/ezc1wfFXbuM?list=PLp24IEwWwtLK9U512g8nmCGngognXsOrP&t=4182)(Sorry for this vedio is in Chinese, though the blackboard is written in English).

Suppose we have a compact Riemann surface $M$, and $\eta$ a [abelian differential of the second kind](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Abelian_differential)(all poles has Residue $0$), and $\widetilde{M}$ the universal covering space of $M$. I saw such an argument:

> Since $\eta$ has no simple poles, its pullback $\pi^* \eta$ in $\widetilde{M}$ has no simple poles too. Again by $\widetilde{M}$ being simply connected. $\int^{z}_{z_0} \pi^* \eta$ defines a meromorphic function $f(z)$ on $\widetilde{M}$ such that $\textrm{d}f = \pi^* \eta$.

The question I has is that altough considering $M$ as a topological manifold, its universal covering map $\pi: \widetilde{M} \to M$  is continuous. But here I believe that $\widetilde{M}$ should be constructed such that it has a $2$-complex structure and the covering map $\pi$ should be a holomorphic map.

My Questions:

1. How to define the complex structure on $ \widetilde{M} $ such that the covering map $\pi$ is a holomorphic map? I think a way to define it is using the homotopy classs on $M$, but such a way does not give a $4g$-gon visualization.
2. If directly constructing $ \widetilde{M} $ via pasting many $4g$-gons, how to paste it together? for $g=2$ it's easy to imagine. But for $g > 2$ I cannot imagine it.
3. Does the proof for Riemann Roch theorem in the effective divisors case rely on the universal covering? In the vedio I watched, it has to pullback some form and integrating it in the boundary of the  $4g$-gon to get the Period matrix.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer questions 1 and 2. Question 3 is rather different and is best handled in another post (we generally ask that you ask [one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671)).

Start by applying the definitions of Riemann surfaces and of covering maps together, to choose an open covering $\{V_i\}$ of the Riemann surface $M$ which serves two purposes simultaneously:

- $\{V_i\}$ forms an atlas for the Riemann surface structure on $M$, so there is a "coordinate chart" homeomorphism $\phi_i : V_i \to W_i \subset \mathbb C$ such that $W_i$ is open and such that each overlap map is holomorphic.
- Each $V_i$ is an evenly covered open set with respect to the covering map $\pi : \widetilde M \to M$, so there is a disjoint union $\pi^{-1}(V_i) = \sqcup_j U_{ij}$ such that each $U_{ij} \subset \widetilde M$ is open and each restriction $\pi \mid U_{ij} : U_{ij} \to V_i$ is a homeomorphism.

Tracing through all of this it is pretty straightforward to prove that $\{U_{ij}\}$ forms an atlas for a Riemann surface structure on $\widetilde M$, using the "coordinate chart" homeomorphisms
$$U_{ij} \xrightarrow{\pi \mid V_{ij}} V_{ij} \xrightarrow{\phi_i} W_i \subset \mathbb C
$$
In fact, each overlap map of the atlas $\{U_{ij}\}$ of $\widetilde M$ is (the restriction of) one of the overlap maps of the atlas $U_i$ of $M$, and hence is holomorphic.

Finally, from this construction it should be pretty clear that the covering map $\pi : \widetilde M \to M$ is holomorphic: each restriction $U_{ij} \mapsto V_i$ is holomorphic because, when expressed in terms of the two coordinate charts $U_{ij} \to W_i$ and $V_i \to W_i$ the restriction is actually the identity map on $W_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly advice. The explanation is nice and detailed.